# What is the best way to migrate a Mail server?

Tags: 10.04, migration, mail-server

I have a Plesk panel mail server with used hard disk space of 480GB out of a total of 900GB. I would like to migrate the plesk panel and data to a new server on raid 1 hard drives(600GB). The mail server has OS Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and the new server that I set up is also on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Are there any commands that can help me achieve this?

The server runs Postfix MTA

Answer (score 1):

Without more specific info about which email server you are using it's gonna be rather difficult to answer.

One thing you can be interested in is imapsync.

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapsync

However, it doesn't support migration of a whole server but rather a separate mailbox.

When it comes to migration of a whole email server it all depends on the format you are keeping your mailboxes. Dovecot's wiki offer a detailed guide about migration of email. http://wiki.dovecot.org/Migration. The simplest way is probably a rsync between two folders / network shares. But as far as I know it would work well with Maildir, I am not sure about mbox.

Comment: I added that I am running postfix.

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=44857

Please check this out, this should help then :)